# How to detect if there is a disconnection to the kafka server

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Hello Kafka community.

I am working on a service that uses the kafka streams API.

Is there a way for my service to detect if it has been disconnected from the kafka server ?

Here is some background. I am trying to add resiliency to my service. That is, if my service is not connected to kafka then it should shoot an alert to notify us that something is bad.

I am using `KafkaStreams.setStateListener()` to install a listener that captures when the kafka stream changes from `RUNNING` to `ERROR` state.

While this helps to capture some errors, there are some other type of errors that are not captured by this state listener mechanism. For example, if the kafka server goes down and the service is no longer connected to the kafka server, then the service remains in `RUNNING` state.

I encountered the case where I see the following exception in my logs

```
Error sending fetch request (sessionId=INVALID, epoch=INITIAL) to node 1001: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.DisconnectException
```

The error above is printed from `FetchSessionHandler.java` in package `org.apache.kafka.clients`.

So is there a way for my service to be detect such errors ?

Answer (score 0):

No. (cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6520)

The problem is, that the underlying consumer does not expose if it lost the connection to the cluster but will just retry to connect internally.